Unity Canvas Width Control: Custom Letterbox
I want to add an option at my game-setting, which controls the width of the screen.
I made a simple record.
Some mobile devices have notch design, punch hole design.
For better experience, i want to make an option to set the letterbox size for user.
The way i did is very rough.

public class LetterboxTestManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float letterbox_percent = 0f;
    public RectTransform grand_rect;
    void Update()
    {
        grand_rect.offsetMin = new Vector2(Screen.width * letterbox_percent * 0.01f, 0);
        grand_rect.offsetMax = new Vector2(-Screen.width * letterbox_percent * 0.01f, 0);

    }
}

But of course, I don't want to make the Stretched Fake Grandparent to all my canvases.
Do you have any idea or advice to achieve this goal without messying up my hierarchy structure?
